# jquery mobile listview refresh exceptions (probably timing)

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

It's obvious that this is a timing issue. I have a jQuery mobile app that I am developing. I am doing the standard method of appending items to a listview. Then calling `refresh` after the items are appended. Yes I have jQuery and jQuery mobile in the head of the html and yes I am using the `'pageinit'` event instead of `$(document).ready()`. Here are the sources:

**The JS**

```
GetApps: function () {
    $('#manage-apps-list').empty();
    $.get('../../../config.xml', function (data) {
        $(data).find('app').each(function () {
            var $this = {}; 
            $this = $(this);
            $('#manage-apps-list').append(
                $('<li/>').append(
                    $('<a/>').attr('href', "#app-settings").attr('data-id', $this.find('id').text()).html($this.find('title').text()).off('click').on('click', function () {GetAppDetail($(this).attr('data-id'));})
                )
            );
        });
    });
    $('#manage-apps-list').listview('refresh');
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id="manage-apps" data-role="page" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Back</a>
        <h2>Manage Apps</h2>
        <ul id="manage-apps-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not the initial page to be seen, but a sub-page. Here is the result:

[image]

I have done this many, many times in my apps, and it always works without issue. I am even using the same versions of `$` and `$.mobile`

I have seen many other questions about this on SO, but they all are missing the call to `refresh`...

Comment: Refresh before `$.get` ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. It IS a timing issue. Your `refresh` method isn't waiting for the list to finish up its append work.  So, a slight restructure of your `get` method is needed :

```
GetApps: function () {
    $('#manage-apps-list').empty();
    $.get('../../../config.xml', function (data) {
      //set up an array for adding li to it.
      var li = [];
      //a temporary element to store "li"
      var $li;
      $(data).find('app').each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         //add the li HTML element to a vairable
         $li = $('<li/>').append(
         //you can also create the anchor tag like this - looks nicer :)
         $('<a/>', {
             "href": "#app-settings",
                 "data-id": $this.find('id').text(),
                 "html": $this.find('title').text()
         }));
         //add this $li to the main array of li
         li.push($li);
      });
      //append li [] to ul
      $('#manage-apps-list').append(li).promise().done(function () {
         //wait for list to be added - thats why you wait for done() event in promise()
         //add the click events to this - event delegation - this way your click event is added only once 
         $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
             //to prevent default click - just in case
             e.preventDefault();
             GetAppDetail($(this).attr('data-id'));
         });
         //then refresh
         $(this).listview().listview("refresh");    
      });
   });
 }
```

#### What I changed in your code

1. You were appending as you got the data in `each`. I pushed that to an array and appended it at the end. So you'll have only one append overall.
2. You were adding `click` event every single time for all the `<a>` tags. This is the behaviour which `onclick` did. Binding event handlers repeatedly is BAD. Thats why even delegation is brought in now.
3. Changed a little bit of element sturcturing. (for example the `<a>` tag)
4. **Important** Finally, to make the `refresh` wait for the `append` to complete, you can add `promise()` to the `append` and wait for it to be `done()`.

**Here's a prototype of what I'm talking abt** : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TdHXL/

Comment: This looks great. I see the mistakes I was making now. I will be sure to try this when I get home, and will be sure to look at and restructure my other applications where I could have also been doing this wrong.

Comment: Glad to help :-) Consider marking this as the right answer if this has worked for you.also,up vote it if you think this will help future visitors :-)

Comment: Yay it worked!! One small possible issue in your post. I believe you accidentally left out `function ()` in your `.done()` Thanks again, and I hope others can learn from this too.